# Advanced Custom Fields color-picker value to menu-item

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

is it possible to assign a CSS class to advanced custom fields menu-item? I managed to display the selected value front end under the menu item. ACF menu-item tutorial shows how to assign font awesome and I get that but how can I get the color in there? Hope someone gets what I mean. Just tell me is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to inline the styles. For example, like this:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
<li><a href="#" style="color: <?php the_field('field_name'); ?>;">Menu1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps :)